# VS 2015 Как отключить проверку ошибок?

Tags: visual-studio

**Используется**
VS 2015
Как отключить проверку ошибок?
Чтобы код не подчёркивался красным цветом.

**Рисунок.**
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а исправить ошибку уже не вариант?

Comment: @rdorn Вариант. Только что исправлять? Из Access вставляю код VBA в VS, а он весь заливается красным. Что не так. скрин: "http://prntscr.com/gdwha0" Вообще можно редактировать так код?

Comment: нет, так редактировать нельзя. VBA и VB это разные языки с похожим синтаксисом. VBA редактируется встроенным редактором офиса